# Finding average in an array without using array class

Tags: c#

I need to calculate the average of the inputted values from an array. Currently the calculation is wrong and I'm not sure how to fix it. I have already tried using a for statement but again it was not calculating properly and gave me the wrong averages. I would be grateful for any help you can give.

```
foreach (int scores in bowlerScores)// a for loop to continue to process the scores
{//by moving through the array and adding each individual score
averageScore += (scores/ SCORE_COUNT);
```

EDIT: just saw int scores and changed to double

Comment: How would you average numbers that were written down on a piece of paper? Forget programming, what's your algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you have, the way to modify it to calculate an average would be as follows:

```cs
int sum = 0;
foreach (int scores in bowlerScores)
{
    sum += scores;
}
double average = (double)sum / (double)SCORE_COUNT;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you're performing integer division each time. I would recommend first summing all the scores, then at the end performing a floating-point division.

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (int scores in bowlerScores)
  sum += scores;

float averageScore = (float)sum / SCORE_COUNT;
```